# When does a comma before "and" apply?

Tags: punctuation

Should there be a comma before "and" in this sentence?

> I look forward to visiting with you and thank you for your consideration.

Comment: It's not needed. However, punctuation is invariably a matter of *style*, so there can be no definitive answer to this question, which is why I'm voting to close it as primarily opinion-based. Does your publisher or institution/course nominate a [style guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide)? If not, choose one you like, and adopt it. Then follow their prescription on the use of commas. For further guidance on using our site, see [ask] and take our [Tour]. :-)

Comment: PS Are you aware that "visiting with you" and "visiting you" mean very different things? There may be regional variations in usage, but most commonly, "visiting with you" would be interpreted as "I'm visiting someone (or somewhere) and you'll be accompanying me on that visit".

Answer (score 1):

To be as clear as possible, it should be two sentences, or have the subject repeated, and then the comma before 'and' would be appropriate:

*I look forward to visiting with you. Thank you for your consideration.*

*I look forward to visiting with you, and I thank you for your consideration.*

A slightly different wording, changing 'thank you' to gerund form, gives a slightly different meaning:

*I look forward to visiting you and thanking you in person.*

Comment: Correct answer. Too many people try to glue separate sentences together with "and" these days.

Answer (score 0):

**That depends what you are trying to say:**

1. "I look forward to visiting with you" and "I thank you for your consideration."
   OR
2. "I look forward to visiting with you" and "Thank you for your consideration."

**What to do:**

1. "I look forward to visiting with you" and "I thank you for your consideration."

**No Comma**

You removed the second "I," so the first clause is independent and the second is dependent. Because they are connected by a coordination conjunction (For, And, Nor, But, Or, Yet, So), there is no comma. The "I" relates to both the first and second half of the sentence.

2. "I look forward to visiting with you" and "Thank you for your consideration."

**Put a Comma**

Both clauses are independent. They each can stand alone; therefore, they require a comma. Nevertheless, this sentence would be very awkward and is not recommended.

Comment: Theresa, this is wrong. Firstly, your prescriptive answer has no grammatical basis and is merely a matter of *convention* or *style*. Does the writer intend that the reader (or speaker) pause before the "and"? If so, then the comma makes sense. Secondly, while it's a common convention to leave out the comma in a sentence like this, that *doesn't* apply for many of the other conjunctions, for which it would be more normal to add a comma. Are you basing your answer on a specific *style manual*? If so, you should [edit] your post to include that detail.

Comment: @Chappo Hasn’t Forgotten Monica, from what I understand, Purdue is a reliable site for grammar and punctuation. I based my answer off their guidelines. Please see https://www.pfw.edu/offices/learning-support/documents/combining-independent-and-dependent-clauses.pdf